# What will be the sum of this series if $a$ and $n$ is odd?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$a$ and $n$ are all odd numbers and are positive

$1+a^1...+a^{2^n-2}+a^{2^n-1}$

I need this for a larger exercise where I determine if this series can be divided by $2^n$

Thanks

Comment: $1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^k = \frac{1 - r^{(k+1)}}{1-r}$

Answer (score 1):

The finite geometric series formula states that $1+r+r^2 + r^3 +\dots + r^{k} = \frac{1-r^{(k+1)}}{1-r}$.

Note that we can just substitute in our values. We get $\frac{1-a^{2^{n}}}{1-a}$.

Im pretty sure there is no way to manipulate this to check divisibility by $2^n$ but someone could correct me if I am wrong.